# How to remove repeated items from a listView in android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I need to populate my `listview` with an `arraylist` of custom elements. Before to try to get it from my API, I created a dummy arraylist, with different value to apply with the adapter. The number of elements I putted there is six. The problem is that the elements after the fourth repeat the title, which is the only variable of my custom object, restarting it from the beginning.
the resulting list is not 1-2-3-4-5-6 but 1-2-3-4-1-2.

MY CUSTOM ADAPTER

```
public class librettoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<librettoDTO> {

Context context;

public librettoAdapter(Context context, int risorsaId,
                          List<librettoDTO> items) {
    super(context, risorsaId, items);
    this.context = context;
}


//metodo getView --> ritorna la view da inserire nella ListView

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //controllo se c'è gia un layout
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.libretto_element, null);

        librettoDTO content = getItem(position);

        TextView textTitolo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_materia);
        textTitolo.setText(content.getTitolo());

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

POPULATING THE LISTVIEW

```
   inputItems = new ArrayList<librettoDTO>();

    /** RITORNA LA CHIAAMATA*/
    /** SOTITUIRE CON LIBRETTODTO */
    /* FACCIAMO FINTA CHE SIA IL RISULTATO DELA CHIAMATA */
    librettoDTO source1 = new librettoDTO("titolo1");
    librettoDTO source2 = new librettoDTO("titolo2");
    librettoDTO source3 = new librettoDTO("titolo3");
    librettoDTO source4 = new librettoDTO("titolo4");
    librettoDTO source5 = new librettoDTO("tsdasdadssa");
    librettoDTO source6 = new librettoDTO("6666666");

    inputItems.add(source1);
    inputItems.add(source2);
    inputItems.add(source3);
    inputItems.add(source4);
    inputItems.add(source5);
    inputItems.add(source6);



    contentItems = new ArrayList<librettoDTO>();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputItems.size(); i++) {

        //librettoDTO item = new librettoDTO(titoli[i]); //INIT DTO GET FROM ARRAY LIST
        librettoDTO item = inputItems.get(i);
        contentItems.add(item);

        //setto la listview e istanzio l'adapter che si prende lo stile xml e l'arraylist di content

        librettoAdapter adapter = new librettoAdapter(getContext(),
                R.layout.libretto_element, contentItems);


        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.libretto_listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //setto il listener
        //listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: That's because convertView is not null. RecyclerView uses the same contentViews and recycle them. I'd suggest you use a RecyclerView.Adapter, which uses a RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecyclerView`
Change your Adapter like this

The Adapter **`librettoAdapter.class`**

```
public class librettoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List inputItems;

    public librettoAdapter(List<String> inputItems) {
        this.inputItems = inputItems;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_text, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String text = inputItems.get(position);
        textview.settext(text);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.inputItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.textview)
        TextView textview;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

        }
    }
}
```

> Setting items to the `list`

```
inputItems = new ArrayList<librettoDTO>();

/** RITORNA LA CHIAAMATA*/
/** SOTITUIRE CON LIBRETTODTO */
/* FACCIAMO FINTA CHE SIA IL RISULTATO DELA CHIAMATA */
librettoDTO source1 = new librettoDTO("titolo1");
librettoDTO source2 = new librettoDTO("titolo2");
librettoDTO source3 = new librettoDTO("titolo3");
librettoDTO source4 = new librettoDTO("titolo4");
librettoDTO source5 = new librettoDTO("tsdasdadssa");
librettoDTO source6 = new librettoDTO("6666666");

inputItems.add(source1);
inputItems.add(source2);
inputItems.add(source3);
inputItems.add(source4);
inputItems.add(source5);
inputItems.add(source6);

librettoAdapter = new librettoAdapter(keyList,valuesList);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(librettoAdapter);
```

Or
if you want to use listview anyway, then try to remove `if (convertView == null)` condition.

Answer (score 0):

solved: just commented the check of convertView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //controllo se c'è gia un layout
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.libretto_element, null);

        librettoDTO content = getItem(position);

        TextView textTitolo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_materia);
        textTitolo.setText(content.getTitolo());

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), content.getTitolo()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //}
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Listview uses cache for view binding.For example if your screen cover just 4 items , to bind 5. item  listview uses one of the items in cache.in four getview call, view will be null and  you are inflating it.But for 5. item it may not be null because of cache usage .in your example , listview used first item from cache to bind 5. item and  inside of if (convertView == null) will not run.first item will be shown for 5. item.

change to :

```
 LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.libretto_element, null);
    }

   librettoDTO content = getItem(position);
   TextView textTitolo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_materia);
   textTitolo.setText(content.getTitolo());

    return convertView;
```